# Как наиболее правильно распарсить

Tags: c#, строки, char, model

как наиболее правильно распарсить данную строку :
4.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 12846

по данной модели :

```
    public DateTime REquestTime { get; set; }

    public string IpOrHost { get; set; }

    public string Routing { get; set; }

    public string AdditionalParams { get; set; }

    public string Result { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public int Size { get; set; }
```

Location добавляется потом , " - -" эти символы можно пропустить 
порядок значения не имеет

Comment: попробуйте регуляркой

Comment: есть одна проблема вместо IP может быть нечто подобное: lj1036.inktomisearch.com

Comment: ну так учитывайте это в регулярке

Comment: Правильно строку не парсить, а заставлять того, кто её записывает, вместо этого сериализировать объектное представление.

Comment: У меня есть исходный лог файл в приведенном формате и мне его надо  считать и занести в  List <Model > параллельно заполнив поле  location   и убрав от туда часть не нужных данных таких как:HTTP/1.1,-0800

Comment: Все пошло дело  с помощью регулярки , спасибо.